How to find the range of a quadratic function we can't use the quadratic formula?
In the question $f(x) = \frac {x}{(1+x^2)}$
$ yx^2 - x + y = 0 $
$x = \frac {1 ± \sqrt {1-4y^2}}{2y}$
We know that $x$ belongs to $\Bbb R$. So, $\frac {1 ± \sqrt {1-4y^2}}{2y}$ also belong to $\Bbb R$.
2y ≠ 0
y ≠ 0           ------ (i)
also, $1-4y^2 ≥ 0$
$y ∈ [\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$
Taking intersection with (i)
$y ∈ [\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}] - \{0\}$
But the correct answer should be $y ∈ [\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$
Why this method is wrong?

Welcome to Math SE. Note that when $y=0$, then $yx^2-x+y=0$ is not a quadratic equation since there is no $x^2$ term. Instead, the equation becomes $-x=0$, i.e., $x=0$ (with these values of $x=y=0$ also satisfying your original $y=f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ equation).

You can only use the quadratic formula for $ax^2+bx+c=0$ when $a\neq0$. So, you need to consider separately the possibility $y=0$, and in that case you get $x=0$, consistent with $y=x/(1+x^2)$.
Hope this helps. :)

What you assumed in your question is wrong. You can't claim $y \neq 0$ because it is zero if $x=0$. Also, notice that $f(x)$ is a continuous function in $\Bbb R$.
But to find the range, you need to observe only one thing:
$|\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}| \leq 1/2$. As $|x|^2 -2|x|+1\geq 0$, for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
Hence $-1/2\leq\dfrac{x}{1+x^2} \leq 1/2$. Your range will be $[-1/2,1/2]$.
The picture shows that $f(x) \in [-1/2,1/2]$. At $x=1$, you get the function's maximum value; at $x=-1$, you will get the minimum value of $f$.
Otherwise, mathematically, you can think another way also as $[-1,1]$ is a closed bounded set, $f$ is a continuous function, and $f([-1,1])$ is also a compact set that is closed and bounded. Now by IVP if $y \in (-1/2,1/2)$ there exists an $c \in (-1,1)$ such that $f(c) = y$. That is $f:[-1,1] \to [-1/2,-1/2]$ is a onto function.

According to the AM-GM inequality, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
1 + x^{2} \geq 2\sqrt{x^{2}} = 2|x| & \Rightarrow \frac{|x|}{1 + x^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{2}\\\\
& \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x}{1 + x^{2}}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}\\\\
& \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{x}{1 + x^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

It seems that your answer needs to address two further issues:  [1] is there an $~x \in \Bbb{R},~$ such that $~f(x) = 1/2.~$  Ditto for $~f(x) = -1/2.~$  [2] Some discussion of the continuity of $~f(x),~$ which would imply that since $~-1/2~$ and $~1/2~$ are both in the range of $~f(x),~$ so is every element $~y,~$ such that $~-1/2 < y < 1/2.~$

Alternative approach:
To analyze the behavior of $~f(x) = \dfrac{x}{1 + x^2},~$ start by examining its 1st derivative.  Then, either also examine its 2nd derivative, or look for alternate approaches.  So,
$$f'(x) = \frac{[ ~1 + x^2 ~] - [ ~x \times 2x ~]}{\left( ~1 + x^2 ~\right)^2} = \frac{1 - x^2}{\left( ~1 + x^2 ~\right)^2}. \tag1 $$
So, you have that $~f'(x) = 0 \iff x \in \{-1, +1 \}.$
At this point, I surmise that the expression on the RHS of (1) above is messy enough that it is worthwhile to avoid taking the 2nd derivative, and instead look for alternative approaches.  The simplest approach is to evaluate $~f(x)~$ for each $~x \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}.$

$\displaystyle f(-2) = \frac{-2}{5}.$

$\displaystyle f(-1) = \frac{-1}{2}.$

$\displaystyle f(0) = \frac{0}{1}.$

$\displaystyle f(1) = \frac{1}{2}.$

$\displaystyle f(2) = \frac{2}{5}.$


From examining the above results, and by taking a closer look at the function $~f(x),~$ it is clear that $f(x)~$ is an odd function.  That is, $~f(-x) = -f(x).~$
So, it is sufficient to analyze the behavior of $~x \in \Bbb{R_{\geq 0}}.$  Once that is done, you can complete the problem by reasoning that $~f(x)~$ is an odd function.

Since the functions $~g(x) = x,~$ and $~h(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2}~$ are each continuous functions, so is the function $~f(x) = \dfrac{x}{1 + x^2}.$
Therefore, since $~f(0) = 0,~$ and $~f(1) = 1/2,~$ you have that for all $~y \in [0,1/2],~$ there exists an $~x \in [0,1]~$ such that $~y = f(x).~$
Also, since $~f'(1) = 0, ~$ and $~f(0), ~f(1), ~f(2) = 0, 1/2, 2/5,~$ respectively, you can conclude that for all $~x \in \Bbb{R_{\geq 0}},~$ that $~f(x)~$ is maximized at $~x = 1.~$
Further, it is clear that while $~f(x) < f(1) = 1/2~$ when $~x > 1,~$ you also have that $~f(x) > 0,~$ when $~x > 1.$
Therefore, the range of $~f[\Bbb{R_{\geq 0}}]~$ must be $~[0,1/2].$
Therefore, since $~f(x)~$ is an odd function, the range of $~f(x)~$ must be $~[-1/2,1/2].$
